# Javascript/jQuery mousewheel zoom for maps

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a map completely made in CSS. You can view it [here](https://rawgithub.com/gkthegr8/chennaimetro/master/index.html). I would like to add a mouse wheel zoom functionality to it (to a particular DIV element - the wrapper of the map). Are there any good plugins for jQuery or a simple JavaScript mouse wheel zoom?

I tried using [Wheelzoom.js](http://www.jacklmoore.com/wheelzoom/) but it is useful only for images. What I am looking at is an effect like in Google Maps. Also, is there a way to set initial zoom position?

Comment: One simple way would be to apply `transform: scale()` for the `#map-wrapper` and detect mousewheel event on `window`.

Comment: Thank you, that was a start! I would like to have a smoother effect on zooming in/out and an initial zoom to be set. Is there a way I can do that?

Comment: Smoother than what? Please check [a demo at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/S2L96/), it includes an initial zoomlevel. (The fiddle doesn't work in Chrome, but works in FF and IE11.)

Comment: I got it working for Chrome as well. But the zoom seems very jerky on Firefox: http://jsfiddle.net/S2L96/1/ (Not concerned about IE).
Also, can I pass an ID or a Class instead of document.body, so that the zoom happens only on that particular div? And will the zoom take effect everywhere on the page, or on that div alone?

Comment: Yep, Chrome needs `mousewheel` listener and `webkit` prefix for the transform property names, I was just lazy... Yes, ofcourse you can pass an element instead of `body`. When passing `id` or `class`you need to change the code a bit. The script will have effect only on the element, which `style.transform` is changed. My fiddle is just a demo... Zooming is jerky in FF only at jsFiddle, I guess. Actually I noticed the jerky zoom when I opened the fiddle in another machine. When I created the snippet locally, there weren't any problems.